# How to output log to file on SD Card in Xamarin Android app?

Tags: android, logging, xamarin, sd-card

I've got a Xamarin Android app that have `Debug.WriteLine` statements throughout the app. These statements appear in the Xamarin console, but I would like them to also be appended to a log file on the phone SD Card.

I think I could develop my own solution, but I'm wondering if there's a built-in way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont think there is a built in way to do this but a simple code can do it for you -

```
using System;
namespace Com.Osfg
{
    public class LogUtils
    {
        String logFilePath = null;

        public LogUtils()
        {
            String path = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path;
            logFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "log.txt");
            if(!System.IO.File.Exists(logFilePath))
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(logFilePath, true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("Starting logging at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        public void Log(String message)
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(logFilePath, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " : " + message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Android has a built in [logging](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/android_debug_log/) function you can use, Android.Util.Log

```
string tag = "myapp";

Log.Info (tag, "this is an info message");
Log.Warn (tag, "this is a warning message");
Log.Error (tag, "this is an error message");
```

Comment: This will log to the rotating logcat buffers which may be overwritten with newer log lines when you want to access them at a later time. And it also does not log to the sd card.